# \textvdots in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, ellipsis

Is there a text-mode vertical ellipsis that I can use directly in LaTeX, e.g., named `\textvdots`, `\texvellipsis` or similar?

I don't mean the unicode engines, but LaTeX, since in {Xe/Lua}LaTeX we could probably type in the vertical ellipsis ⋮ directly. Moreover, I don't wish to switch to math mode, such as in `\(\vdots\)`: it produces some undesirable vertical space above the symbol. I've already tried [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and [`symbols-a4.pdf`](//texdoc.net/pkg/comprehensive).

Comment: We don't delete Q&A with upvotes. It's OK if it stays around. Other users might have similar problems and find it useful after all.

Comment: Well, why not let it be? It does not create a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `\vdots` is defined as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\vdots}{%
  \vbox{%
    \baselineskip 4\p@
    \lineskiplimit \z@
    \kern 6\p@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}%
  }%
}
```

with no indication of using math mode. So you can just use `\vdots` within the text, or define `\textvdots` for using in text as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\textvdots\vdots

\begin{document}

This is \verb|\textvdots| \textvdots{} or \verb|\vdots| \vdots{} in text mode.

\end{document}
```

If the command did not have the above construction that allowed for using within text/math mode, then you can use (for example, when considering `\alpha` that only works in math mode):

```
\newcommand{\textalpha}{$\alpha$}
```

or something more intricate

```
\newcommand{\textalpha}{\ifmmode \alpha\else $\alpha$\fi}
```

the works in both text and math mode.

---

For reducing the vertical stretch, redefine `\textvdots` to be similar to `\vdots` only with a smaller `\baselineskip`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textalpha}{%
  \vbox{%
    \baselineskip 3\p@
    \lineskiplimit \z@
    \kern 6\p@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is \verb|$\textalpha$| \textalpha{} and \vdots{} in text mode, for comparison.

\end{document}
```